# Logback выводит только String

Tags: java, логирование, slf4j

Подключил через dependency SLF4j-api и Logback.
Внутри класса пишу

```
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Printer.class);
```

далее есть метод

```
public static void collectionPrint(ArrayList list) {

    Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        log.info("Printer ",iterator.next());
    }
}
```

Он должен выводит коллекцию, через `System.out.println` он выводит всё корректно.
А в логгере пишет

> 20:57:02.527 [main] INFO com.epam.as.coffeevan.service.BeverageFinder - Printer

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый параметр логгирующих методов в SLF4J это *шаблон* строки. Вы должны использовать макрос `{}` в тех местах, где нужно выполнить подстановку. Например:

```
logger.debug("Result={}, time={}", result, time);
```

Соответственно в вашем случае это будет:

```
log.info("Printer {}", iterator.next());
```

---

Обязательно прочитайте FAQ про [параметризованное логгирование](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#logging_performance).

Comment: Блин я знал же это) просто забыл) спасибо Вам!